# How do I join 3 tables with different columns? Getting data type error SQL Big Query

Tags: sql, datatables, google-bigquery, union

I am trying to create a view from 3 different tables. I keep getting an error 'Column 2 in UNION DISTINCT has incompatible types: INT64, STRING, STRING at [165:1]'

What am I doing wrong? The line 165:1 where it is flagging is when the next table starts. Is there a better way to merge 3 tables with different columns?

Below is script for the view

````
SELECT Date,
Active_View_Impressions__AdWords,
Active_View_Measurable_Cost__AdWords,
Active_View_Measurable_Impressions__AdWords,
All_Conv___AdWords,
SPLIT(Campaign__AdWords,'|')[safe_ordinal(1)] as Location,SPLIT(Campaign__AdWords,'|')[safe_ordinal(2)] as Market_Type,
Click_Assisted_Conv___AdWords,
Clicks__AdWords,
Conversions__AdWords,
Cost__AdWords,
Data_Source_id,
Data_Source_type,
Device__AdWords,
Engagements__AdWords,
Impr__Assisted_Conv___AdWords,
Impressions__AdWords,
Interactions__AdWords,
Invalid_Clicks__AdWords,
Network_With_Search_Params__AdWords,
Total_absolute_top_impressions__AdWords,
Total_Position__AdWords,
Total_top_impressions__AdWords,
Video_views__AdWords,
View_through_Conv___AdWords,
Views__AdWords,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
FROM`inbr.Adwords_02.all_funnel_data_view` 

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT Date,
Data_Source_id,
Data_Source_type,
Actions__Facebook_Ads,
Amount_Spent__Facebook_Ads,
Attribution_Window__Facebook_Ads,
Buying_Type__Facebook_Ads,
SPLIT(Campaign_Name__Facebook_Ads,'|')[safe_ordinal(1)] as Market,SPLIT(Campaign_Name__Facebook_Ads,'|')[safe_ordinal(2)] as Market_Type,
Campaign_Objective__Facebook_Ads,
Check_ins__Facebook_Ads,
Clicks_all__Facebook_Ads,
Event_Responses__Facebook_Ads,
Impressions__Facebook_Ads,
Link_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
n_10_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
n_3_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Outbound_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Engagement__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Likes__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Mentions__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Tab_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Photo_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Comments__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Engagement__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Reactions__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Shares__Facebook_Ads,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
FROM`inbr.Facebook_Ads_02.all_funnel_data_view`

UNION DISTINCT 

SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE) Date,
Data_Source_type,
Data_Source_id,
Campaign,
Data_Source,
Data_Source_name,
Data_Source_type_name,
Ad_legacy__AdWords,
Ad_Group_Name__AdWords,
Ad_Type__AdWords,
SPLIT(Campaign__AdWords,'|')[safe_ordinal(1)] as Market,SPLIT(Campaign__AdWords,'|')[safe_ordinal(2)] as Market_Type,
City__AdWords,
Description__AdWords,
Description_Line_1__AdWords,
Description_Line_2__AdWords,
Device__AdWords,
Expanded_Text_Ad_Description_2__AdWords,
Expanded_Text_Ad_Headline_3__AdWords,
Headline_1__AdWords,
Headline_2__AdWords,
KeywordPlacement__AdWords,
Metro__AdWords,
Network__AdWords,
Network_With_Search_Params__AdWords,
Quality_Score__AdWords,
Region__AdWords,
Clicks__AdWords,
Cost__AdWords,
Engagements__AdWords,
Impressions__AdWords,
Interactions__AdWords,
Invalid_Clicks__AdWords,
Total_absolute_top_impressions__AdWords,
Total_Position__AdWords,
Total_top_impressions__AdWords,
Video_views__AdWords,
Views__AdWords,
Video_impressions__AdWords,
Views_100__AdWords,
Active_View_Impressions__AdWords,
Active_View_Measurable_Cost__AdWords,
Active_View_Measurable_Impressions__AdWords,
All_Conv___AdWords,
Click_Assisted_Conv___AdWords,
Conversions__AdWords,
Impr__Assisted_Conv___AdWords,
SmileSnap_Button_Click_mo_tid_Med___inbr___AdWords_Keyword__AdWords,
Thank_You_Form_mo_tid_Med___inbr___AdWords_Keyword__AdWords,
View_through_Conv___AdWords,
Ad_Name__Facebook_Ads,
Ad_Set_Name__Facebook_Ads,
Age__Facebook_Ads,
Attribution_Window__Facebook_Ads,
Buying_Type__Facebook_Ads,
Campaign_Name__Facebook_Ads,
Campaign_Objective__Facebook_Ads,
Conversion_Device__Facebook_Ads,
Device_Platform__Facebook_Ads,
DMA_Region__Facebook_Ads,
Impression_Device__Facebook_Ads,
Link__Facebook_Ads,
Placement__Facebook_Ads,
Gender__Facebook_Ads,
Platform__Facebook_Ads,
n_10_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
n_3_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
n_30_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Plays__Facebook_Ads,
Video_thruplay__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_100__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_25__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_50__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_75__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_95__Facebook_Ads,
Button_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
Link_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
Outbound_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
Check_ins__Facebook_Ads,
Event_Responses__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Engagement__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Likes__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Mentions__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Tab_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Photo_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Comments__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Engagement__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Reactions__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Shares__Facebook_Ads,
Actions__Facebook_Ads,
Amount_Spent__Facebook_Ads,
Clicks_all__Facebook_Ads,
Impressions__Facebook_Ads,
Thank_You_Form_mo_tid_Med___inbr___Facebook_Conversion__Facebook_Ads,
Thank_You_Form_V2_mo_tid_Med___inbr___Facebook_Conversion__Facebook_Ads,
n_100_In_View_Impressions__Facebook_Ads,
Custom_Events__Facebook_Ads,
Landing_Page_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Leads__Facebook_Ads,
Leads_Form__Facebook_Ads,
Ad_Group_ID__The_Trade,
Ad_Group_Name__The_Trade,
Advertiser_ID__The_Trade,
Advertiser_Name__The_Trade,
Advertiser_Total_Cost__The_Trade,
Partner_Cost__The_Trade_1,
Bids__The_Trade,
Campaign_ID__The_Trade,
Campaign_Name__The_Trade,
Clicks__The_Trade,
Impressions__The_Trade,
Partner_ID__The_Trade,
Site__The_Trade,
City__The_Trade,
Country__The_Trade,
Metro__The_Trade,
Region__The_Trade,
Player_25_Complete__The_Trade,
Player_50_Complete__The_Trade,
Player_75_Complete__The_Trade,
Player_Close__The_Trade,
Player_Collapse__The_Trade,
Player_Completed_Views__The_Trade,
Player_Engaged_Views__The_Trade,
Player_Error__The_Trade,
Player_Expansion__The_Trade,
Player_Full_Screen__The_Trade,
Player_Invitation_Accept__The_Trade,
Player_Mute__The_Trade,
Player_Pause__The_Trade,
Player_Resume__The_Trade,
Player_Rewind__The_Trade,
Player_Skip__The_Trade,
Player_Starts__The_Trade,
Player_Unmute__The_Trade,
Player_Views__The_Trade,
Video_Was_Trackable__The_Trade,
Video_Was_Viewable__The_Trade,
n_01___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_02___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_03___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_04___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_05___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_06___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_01___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_02___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_03___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_04___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_05___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_06___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_01___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_02___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_03___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_04___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_05___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_06___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_01___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_02___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_03___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_04___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_05___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_06___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade
FROM`inbr.AX_Trade.AX_Trade` ```
````

Comment: I am guessing that you could significantly simplify this query to illustrate the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to error message there are type mismatch for column 2 in three tables. So, I have casted second column of first table as string. Please check now.

```
SELECT Date,
cast(Active_View_Impressions__AdWords as string),
Active_View_Measurable_Cost__AdWords,
Active_View_Measurable_Impressions__AdWords,
All_Conv___AdWords,
SPLIT(Campaign__AdWords,'|')[safe_ordinal(1)] as Location,SPLIT(Campaign__AdWords,'|')[safe_ordinal(2)] as Market_Type,
Click_Assisted_Conv___AdWords,
Clicks__AdWords,
Conversions__AdWords,
Cost__AdWords,
Data_Source_id,
Data_Source_type,
Device__AdWords,
Engagements__AdWords,
Impr__Assisted_Conv___AdWords,
Impressions__AdWords,
Interactions__AdWords,
Invalid_Clicks__AdWords,
Network_With_Search_Params__AdWords,
Total_absolute_top_impressions__AdWords,
Total_Position__AdWords,
Total_top_impressions__AdWords,
Video_views__AdWords,
View_through_Conv___AdWords,
Views__AdWords,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
FROM`inbr.Adwords_02.all_funnel_data_view` 

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT Date,
Data_Source_id,
Data_Source_type,
Actions__Facebook_Ads,
Amount_Spent__Facebook_Ads,
Attribution_Window__Facebook_Ads,
Buying_Type__Facebook_Ads,
SPLIT(Campaign_Name__Facebook_Ads,'|')[safe_ordinal(1)] as Market,SPLIT(Campaign_Name__Facebook_Ads,'|')[safe_ordinal(2)] as Market_Type,
Campaign_Objective__Facebook_Ads,
Check_ins__Facebook_Ads,
Clicks_all__Facebook_Ads,
Event_Responses__Facebook_Ads,
Impressions__Facebook_Ads,
Link_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
n_10_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
n_3_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Outbound_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Engagement__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Likes__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Mentions__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Tab_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Photo_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Comments__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Engagement__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Reactions__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Shares__Facebook_Ads,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
FROM`inbr.Facebook_Ads_02.all_funnel_data_view`

UNION DISTINCT 

SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE) Date,
Data_Source_type,
Data_Source_id,
Campaign,
Data_Source,
Data_Source_name,
Data_Source_type_name,
Ad_legacy__AdWords,
Ad_Group_Name__AdWords,
Ad_Type__AdWords,
SPLIT(Campaign__AdWords,'|')[safe_ordinal(1)] as Market,SPLIT(Campaign__AdWords,'|')[safe_ordinal(2)] as Market_Type,
City__AdWords,
Description__AdWords,
Description_Line_1__AdWords,
Description_Line_2__AdWords,
Device__AdWords,
Expanded_Text_Ad_Description_2__AdWords,
Expanded_Text_Ad_Headline_3__AdWords,
Headline_1__AdWords,
Headline_2__AdWords,
KeywordPlacement__AdWords,
Metro__AdWords,
Network__AdWords,
Network_With_Search_Params__AdWords,
Quality_Score__AdWords,
Region__AdWords,
Clicks__AdWords,
Cost__AdWords,
Engagements__AdWords,
Impressions__AdWords,
Interactions__AdWords,
Invalid_Clicks__AdWords,
Total_absolute_top_impressions__AdWords,
Total_Position__AdWords,
Total_top_impressions__AdWords,
Video_views__AdWords,
Views__AdWords,
Video_impressions__AdWords,
Views_100__AdWords,
Active_View_Impressions__AdWords,
Active_View_Measurable_Cost__AdWords,
Active_View_Measurable_Impressions__AdWords,
All_Conv___AdWords,
Click_Assisted_Conv___AdWords,
Conversions__AdWords,
Impr__Assisted_Conv___AdWords,
SmileSnap_Button_Click_mo_tid_Med___inbr___AdWords_Keyword__AdWords,
Thank_You_Form_mo_tid_Med___inbr___AdWords_Keyword__AdWords,
View_through_Conv___AdWords,
Ad_Name__Facebook_Ads,
Ad_Set_Name__Facebook_Ads,
Age__Facebook_Ads,
Attribution_Window__Facebook_Ads,
Buying_Type__Facebook_Ads,
Campaign_Name__Facebook_Ads,
Campaign_Objective__Facebook_Ads,
Conversion_Device__Facebook_Ads,
Device_Platform__Facebook_Ads,
DMA_Region__Facebook_Ads,
Impression_Device__Facebook_Ads,
Link__Facebook_Ads,
Placement__Facebook_Ads,
Gender__Facebook_Ads,
Platform__Facebook_Ads,
n_10_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
n_3_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
n_30_Second_Video_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Plays__Facebook_Ads,
Video_thruplay__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_100__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_25__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_50__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_75__Facebook_Ads,
Video_Watches_at_95__Facebook_Ads,
Button_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
Link_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
Outbound_Clicks__Facebook_Ads,
Check_ins__Facebook_Ads,
Event_Responses__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Engagement__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Likes__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Mentions__Facebook_Ads,
Page_Tab_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Photo_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Comments__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Engagement__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Reactions__Facebook_Ads,
Post_Shares__Facebook_Ads,
Actions__Facebook_Ads,
Amount_Spent__Facebook_Ads,
Clicks_all__Facebook_Ads,
Impressions__Facebook_Ads,
Thank_You_Form_mo_tid_Med___inbr___Facebook_Conversion__Facebook_Ads,
Thank_You_Form_V2_mo_tid_Med___inbr___Facebook_Conversion__Facebook_Ads,
n_100_In_View_Impressions__Facebook_Ads,
Custom_Events__Facebook_Ads,
Landing_Page_Views__Facebook_Ads,
Leads__Facebook_Ads,
Leads_Form__Facebook_Ads,
Ad_Group_ID__The_Trade,
Ad_Group_Name__The_Trade,
Advertiser_ID__The_Trade,
Advertiser_Name__The_Trade,
Advertiser_Total_Cost__The_Trade,
Partner_Cost__The_Trade_1,
Bids__The_Trade,
Campaign_ID__The_Trade,
Campaign_Name__The_Trade,
Clicks__The_Trade,
Impressions__The_Trade,
Partner_ID__The_Trade,
Site__The_Trade,
City__The_Trade,
Country__The_Trade,
Metro__The_Trade,
Region__The_Trade,
Player_25_Complete__The_Trade,
Player_50_Complete__The_Trade,
Player_75_Complete__The_Trade,
Player_Close__The_Trade,
Player_Collapse__The_Trade,
Player_Completed_Views__The_Trade,
Player_Engaged_Views__The_Trade,
Player_Error__The_Trade,
Player_Expansion__The_Trade,
Player_Full_Screen__The_Trade,
Player_Invitation_Accept__The_Trade,
Player_Mute__The_Trade,
Player_Pause__The_Trade,
Player_Resume__The_Trade,
Player_Rewind__The_Trade,
Player_Skip__The_Trade,
Player_Starts__The_Trade,
Player_Unmute__The_Trade,
Player_Views__The_Trade,
Video_Was_Trackable__The_Trade,
Video_Was_Viewable__The_Trade,
n_01___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_02___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_03___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_04___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_05___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_06___Click_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_01___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_02___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_03___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_04___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_05___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_06___Time_Weighted_Decay_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_01___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_02___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_03___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_04___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_05___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_06___View_Through_Conversion__The_Trade,
n_01___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_02___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_03___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_04___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_05___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade,
n_06___Conversion_Touch__The_Trade
FROM`inbr.AX_Trade.AX_Trade
```

Comment: You are most welcome @gitmom. Good work. Best wishes.